# Scala regex get parameters in path

Tags: regex, scala

regex noob here.

example path:

```
home://Joseph/age=20/race=human/height=170/etc
```

Using regex, how do I grab everything after the "=" between the /Joseph/ path and /etc? I'm trying to create a list like

```
[20, human, 170]
```

So far I have

```
val pattern = ("""(?<=Joseph/)[^/]*""").r
val matches = pattern.findAllIn(path)
```

The pattern lets me just get "age=20" but I thought findAllIn would let me find all of the "parameter=" matches. And after that, I'm not sure how I would use regex to just obtain the "20" in "age=20", etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your pattern looks for the pattern directly after `Joseph/`, which is why only `age=20` matched, maybe just look after `=`?

```
val s = "home://Joseph/age=20/race=human/height=170/etc"
// s: String = home://Joseph/age=20/race=human/height=170/etc

val pattern = "(?<==)[^/]*".r
// pattern: scala.util.matching.Regex = (?<==)[^/]*

pattern.findAllIn(s).toList
// res3: List[String] = List(20, human, 170)
```

Answer (score 1):

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/TJoG0q/1)

```
(?:(?<=/Joseph/)|\G(?!\A)/)[^=]+=([^=/]+)
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/VPTnxl)

```
object Main extends App {
    val path = "home://Joseph/age=20/race=human/height=170/etc"
    val pattern = ("""(?:(?<=/Joseph/)|\G(?!\A)/)[^=]+=([^=/]+)""").r
    pattern.findAllIn(path).matchData foreach {
        m => println(m.group(1))
    }
}
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
home://Joseph/age=20/race=human/height=170/etc
```

#### Output

```
20
human
170
```

---

### Explanation

- `(?:(?<=/Joseph/)|\G(?!\A)/)` Match the following

  - `(?<=/Joseph/)` Positive lookbehind ensuring what precedes matches `/Joseph/` literally
  - `\G(?!\A)/` Assert position at the end of the previous match and match `/` literally
- `[^=]+` Match one or more of any character except `=`
- `=` Match this literally
- `([^=/]+)` Capture one or more of any character except `=` and `/` into capture group 1